# Perforce P4 command line: How to find files in the repository?

Tags: file, command-line, find, perforce

In P4V, I can enter the directory in the "Search in:" field, enter a file pattern such as "*.c" in the "Name contains:" field and hit "Find".

How do I do that using P4 on the command line or using the P4 APIs? I want to write a C# program to do this.

Comment: I'm working in Windows env and Command shell.

Answer (score 8):

In the shell:

```
p4 files '//.../*.c'
```

I've not used the C# P4 API, but I've used a few others, and they all have something like:

```
p4.run( 'files', '//.../*.c' )
```

A useful variant of 'p4 files' is 'p4 fstat', which has all kinds of filtering flags and yields a rich bouquet of state attributes.

Comment: You could be slightly more succinct with the command line would be 'p4 files //....c.  The first three dots will match file or directory, and the last .c will match the extension.

Comment: Didn't work for me:  
`p4 files '//.../myfile.txt'`
    
`Path 'c:\'//.../myfile.txt'' is not under client's root C:\Users\user\Perforce\myWS'.`
`

Comment: I would need to escape the asterisk to make the first solution work.
My environment doesn't accept the second solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

With double quote it worked: `p4 files "//.../web.config"`